# How can I disable EXIF auto rotation on a Nikon D7000?

Tags: metadata, nikon-d7000

In older Nikon DSLRs like the D70 there was an option to not add image rotation information to the EXIF data of the image. I can't find this option in a D7000. Can anyone please confirm that it is not available anymore or where I can find it?

Comment: I'm curious why you _wouldn't_ want this there. It's so convenient, and you can always either ignore it or batch-rotate based on the tag.

Comment: +1 to MattDM. Also, if you want this meta data out, then you may want other meta data out too. In that case, some meta data stripping tool might be better.

Comment: It's a matter of the workflow. My personal collection of digital images goes back till the early 2000th and at that time I had no camera capable of auto rotation. For me, it is better to have all images in the same "format".

Comment: I don't want auto rotate either, because I shoot a series at 45° angle of the camera and believe me you don't want to have alternating pictures :(

Comment: @Ivo, thanks! That's a great reason that hadn't occurred to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is there, in the Setup menu (the one with the wrench/spanner icon). It's called Auto Image Rotation, and it comes between 'Image Content' and 'Image Dust Off ref photo'.

Comment: No, that's 'Rotate Tall' in the Playback Menu. Essentially, Rotate Tall rotates images that have their orientation recorded by Auto Image Rotation. Simple eh? :)

Comment: Ah, nice. I retract my comment.

Comment: Ok, now I found it. The German translation was somehow unexpected :-) Mmmh, I think Nikon should really restructure the menu points. There are 3 different points where you define how pictures are taken. Doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Indeed, evidently they need an injection of Teutonic efficiency! :)